# C++: test if private field exists and get access on it (reflection)

Tags: c++, reflection

I'm absolutely new to C++, just wrote a few lines yet.

I have access on an singleton object and I have a public available .h-file for that object.
I can call the methods which are described in the .h-file without a problem.

But now my problem:

I know, that most implementations of that object contains a special Vector-field, which is not available in the .h-file.

Is there a way to detect, if an object has a special field with a known name, and if yes, how can I access it?

Sadly the code of that remote object is not under my control. I can just use the object, but not modify the base or source of it.

In JAVA, that would be simple reflection.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Funny, I just had to make a SFINAE thing to do this (or rather different functions for whether it's found) in some answer yesterday. It works out a lot better if you only need it to compile when it has the member.

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry it's not my wish, I love to teach myself, but business is sadly not easy all the time.

Comment: @AndyProwl Next time I'm following your lead...

Comment: @MartinM., Just to make sure I understand correctly, does this include the possibility of overloading one function based on the presence of a data member, like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=200ce7dd4c270d3bfdea6df8628f6e4e-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f) (more credit to Xeo than me on that one)?

Comment: @chris He doesn't have direct access to the implementation, only a base interface.

Comment: It's a bit difficult here: I can get a singleton service-instance. I have a .h-file for that instance with e.g. write()/read().. and I know that in most cases, that singleton has a field named "childs". Now I would like to access and modify one of that chields, but this is not possible without reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ doesn't have reflection, and if something isn't public in a class, you can't get to it [within "non-tricks" C++ - and with tricks, it means using things like "knowing it's 18 bytes into the structure, which will break as soon as you use a slightly different architecture, or someone alters the singleton, or some other changes].